# how to use :checked for responsive navbar using css

Tags: html, css, checked, unchecked

I have added a checkbox with the class checkButton.

```
      <div class="hamburger">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
        <label for="check" class="checkButton">
          <i class="fas fa-bars" style="font-size: 35px"></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="navItems">
        <li><a href="#home" class="navItem active">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" class="navItem">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects" class="navItem">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ourTeam" class="navItem">OUR TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="navItem">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Then I added some CSS for how it should look when clicked.

```
    ul{
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 0;
        right: 100%;
        background-color: #e54136;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
```

Can you please tell me how to use `:clicked` and link it so that my `ul` changes on clicking the `checkButton` class.
Here's what I did and it's not working.

```
    ul{
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 0;
        right: 100%;
        background-color: #e54136;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
```

When it is checked, it must bring `right: 0;` in `ul`.

```
.checkButton:checked ~ ul{
    right: 0%;
}
```

Comment: where is `ul` placed in the html ? what should happen after the checkbox is checked ?

Comment: Please tell me how do I make right: 0; when checked. @MajiD

Comment: if you need to show the menu on click, it need a little bit of javascript. just show me where your `ul` placed in the html so i can help you

Comment: @MajiD please check now. I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```js
var check = document.querySelector('.hamburger > .checkButton');
var menu = document.querySelector('.navItems');

check.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  menu.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
ul {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 0;
  right: 100%;
  background-color: #e54136;
  transition: all .5s;
}

ul.show {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="hamburger">
  <button class="checkButton">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<ul class="navItems">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) references a sibling of the element on the left.

Your `ul` is not a sibling of your `input`. It is a child of a sibling of the input's grandparent (or *first cousin, once removed*).

There is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) to select the `ul` from the `input` so to get this to work, you'd need to rearrange your markup.

… but don't. CSS alone is not a good tool for this problem. Use JavaScript. Take advantage of accessibility tools like [ARIA](http://www.ashleysheridan.co.uk/blog/Making+an+Accessible+Hamburger+Menu).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example of how it should work without JS:

```css
label {
  cursor:pointer;
}
input +  nav {
  visibility:hidden;
}
input:checked + nav {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<label for="a1">Hamburger button, click me</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="a1">
<nav>Hidden menu</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

ul ~ p Selects every  element that are preceded by a

element.
For better understanding read https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

but if u dont want to use js of jQuery

here is the code with checkbox

```css
ul.navItems{
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 0;
        right: 100%;
        background-color: #e54136;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
    .hamburger input:checked + ul.navItems {
        right: 0%;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="hamburger">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
        <ul class="navItems">
            <li><a href="#home" class="navItem active">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services" class="navItem">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects" class="navItem">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ourTeam" class="navItem">OUR TEAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="navItem">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```